# Nib/Xib object lifecycle

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Right now I have a rootViewController that calls another ViewController that is a nib file via:

```
self.popViewController = PopViewController(nibName: "PopUpViewController_iPhone6Plus", bundle: bundle)
```

Where this init is:

```
 override public init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

After rootViewController instantiates PopViewController it brings it up via:

```
self.popViewController.showInView(self, animated: true)
```

Where showInView is:

```
 func showInView(myRootViewController : MyRootViewController!, animated: Bool)
{
    self.myRootViewController = myRootViewController
    myRootViewController.view.addSubview(self.view)
    myTextField.delegate = self
    
    if animated
    {
        self.showAnimate()
    }
}
```

Where myTextField is an IBOutlet for PopViewController. I realised that if I put `myTextField.delegate = self` before    `myRootViewController.view.addSubview(self.view)` then I get an error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` but if I put it afterwards everything is fine.

I've looked at the documentations for the [Nib files](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html) and my question is:

Is the reason why I'm getting the error when I put `myTextField.delegate = self` before `myRootViewController.view.addSubview(self.view)` because the IBOutlets don't get connected before the nib's view is shown?

Also:
Why does loading the nib via:
`self.popViewController = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("PopViewController_iPhone6", owner: PopViewControllerSwift.self, options: nil).first as! PopViewControllerSwift`

throw an error:

`'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<DeckWheel.PopUpAddDeckViewControllerSwift 0x10026cbe0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init'ing a view controller with the NIB does not load it immediately. The NIB is not actually loaded until the view controller's `view` is queried.

From [the docs for `UIViewController`'s `init(nibName:bundle:)` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:):

> The nib file you specify is not loaded right away. It is loaded the first time the view controller’s view is accessed. If you want to perform additional initialization after the nib file is loaded, override the `viewDidLoad` method and perform your tasks there.

Of course, the outlet connections set up in the NIB can't be connected until the NIB is loaded. So, until you query the `view`, your outlets are `nil`.

Comment: But for the second question even though I'm setting the textField delegate after the view is accessed it still throws the key-value error

Comment: The object you send to the `owner` parameter is what it tries to hook the IBOutlets up to.  You are sending the actual class instead of an instance of the class which doesn't a property for any of the outlets

Comment: @YellowPillow, "for the second question", you should create, you know, a *second question*. Although dan did answer it, above.